# Cannot alter model attribute directly when carrierwave uploader is mounted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am using activeadmin, and the following code is supposed to assign a photo to a Card if found in a directory.

The Card model won't accept the new photo, it never assigns the new value, save returns true.

UPDATE: The problem is that the attribute has a carrierwave uploader mounted on it. Commenting out the mount made it work, but it really isn't an acceptable solution since this is an action that will have to be made repeatedly... Is there a way to unmount the uploader or set the attribute value directly with the uploader mounted? I can't seem to find anything on that on the web...

UPDATE: Even `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("update cards set photo='#{f.to_s}' where id=#{card.id};")` fails when carrierwave is mounted... It's taken over for good I guess

UPDATE: It turns out my question is a duplicate of
[Manually updating attributes mounted by Carrierwave Uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950042/manually-updating-attributes-mounted-by-carrierwave-uploader)

from the log:

```
Card Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `cards`.* FROM `cards` WHERE `cards`.`gatherer_id` = 244675 LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Card Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `cards`.* FROM `cards` WHERE `cards`.`id` = 1377 LIMIT 1
SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `cards` SET `photo` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2013-11-22 11:20:44' WHERE `cards`.`id` = 1377
(4.1ms)  COMMIT
```

After carrierwave is not mounted and a value for the attribute is updated just fine and afterwards, when carrierwave is mounted again it returns the file location according to the uploader store_dir normally. The only problem is I cannot set the value when the uploader is mounted. As a last resort I will do it with plain old sql, I just don't like the idea much.

activeadmin action:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Import FTP photos' do
  menu label: 'Import FTP photos', parent: 'Cards'

  #action_item do
  #  link_to 'View Site', '/'
  #end

  content do
    require 'fileutils'

    para 'Importing photos...'

    from_dir = 'var/uploads/card_photos'
    uploads_dir = 'public/uploads/card/photo/'

    Dir.foreach(from_dir) do |f|
      next if f == '.' or f == '..'

      from_file = from_dir + '/' + f.to_s

      id = f.gsub(/\.\w+$/, '')
      card = Card.find_by_gatherer_id(id)
      if card
        to_dir = uploads_dir+card.id.to_s
        to_file = to_dir + '/' + f.to_s

        Dir.mkdir(to_dir) if Dir.new(to_dir).nil?
        FileUtils.remove(to_file) if FileTest.exists?(to_file)
        FileUtils.mv(from_file, to_file)

        card.photo = f.to_s
        card.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

card model

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  belongs_to :card_set
  belongs_to :card_artist

  def to_s
    caption
  end

  private

  def card_params
    params.permit!
  end
end
```

Comment: Any chance of the logs or PRY on create or raise params.inspect?

Comment: I have added some information from the log in the description, I don't know what PRY is, I am truly new to rails. My bad about referring to params, nothing is passed through params here, it's all batch